# Eclipse Plug-in - Capture the paste event from mouse popup menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin, popupmenu

Recently I have developed a plugin for education purpose. The main functionality of this plug-in is capture the copy & paste action in the editor.

I have used ICommandService class to capture the copy & paste event.  It is working successfully in Keyboard shortcuts ( Cntl+V) and eclipse main menu ( Edit--> Paste)

But same is not working while using Mouse Right Click -> Popup Menu -> Paste.

Is there any way to capture the Mouse Popup Menu Selection.

I am using following code to capture the Paste event.

```
ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
Command defaultCopyCommand = commandService.getCommand(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_COPY);
Command defaultPasteCommand = commandService.getCommand(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_PASTE);
defaultCopyCommand.addExecutionListener(iel);
 defaultPasteCommand.addExecutionListener(iel);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Updated!!!!

Hi @greg-449, Thanks for your input. Finally used Plugin-Spy to capture the details.  Following details are showing when paste operation is called through the Mouse Menu Paste Action [Image](https://ibb.co/XxRrYj5). I can see the definition identifies is same & it was fire in both Key shortcuts and eclipse main menu option.  Also I have noticed that Current active part of editor is "ComplilationUnitEditor" & active menu contributions is #CompilationUnitEdiorContext.  Is there any way to capture the CompilationUnitEdiorContext changed event in current workbench window?

Comment: The Paste in the editor menu uses `TextOperationAction` which calls the editor paste action directly. Not sure if there is anyway to handle that.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, Thanks for your input. I have gone through some of sites and examples. And finally used Plugin-Spy to capture the details.